# How to clearly distinguish all emails related to another domain inside personal gmail account?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, email-forwarding, alias

I have an email address of my own very small business domain (A) forwarding to my personal gmail account (B) so I only access it, and send as, inside my personal gmail (B).

How do I separate all email related to that domain inside my personal gmail?

I'd like an overview of everything without being distracted by my personal email.
(Possibly some kind of folder or label so I can save a shortcut to it.)

Answer (score 1):

In the page where you specify the outside mail link, you can also specify a label to attach to all the email, you can also specify that you want it to skip the inbox.

To make it easy to see those emails you can then use the multiple inboxes. You enable that through settings/advanced; then you are given a new tab in the settings, and can specify the label you want to include in one of the sections.

If you decide to keep the ingested email in the main inbox, you can then make the label standout by picking an appropriate color.

Answer (score 0):

I find a mail client on my pc and mobile a better solution.  I use **thunderbird** on my pc and **fairmail** on my mobile.

They can both handle

- multiple accounts,
- with individual signatures
- and individual folders.
- When I reply to an email, they give me a choice about which account to use.
- I can different colours on fairmail and I use unicode icons as part of my account name in thunderbird.

I have thunderbird set up as **pop**, because I want the repository on my desktop.  And I have fairmail set up as **imap**.

[Download Thunderbird here](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/download/)

[Download Fairmail here](https://email.faircode.eu/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Really !  Its unclear